# Differents between Task.get() and dont wait for execution

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, javafx

I have the following Task-Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import static controller.Controller_main.MAX_SELECTION_TABS;
import static controller.Controller_main.currentUser;
import static controller.Controller_main.tabController;
import database.connection.DatabaseThreadExecuter;
import databasebeans.DatabaseCustomer;
import databasebeans.DatabaseSelektion;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import utility.MessageHelper;
import static utility.MessageHelper.createInformaionMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class CreateSelections extends Task<Void>{

    private int activeSelections;
    private DatabaseSelektion sql;
    private int position;
    private TabPane tabpane;
    private Image image;

    public CreateSelections(int activeSelections, DatabaseSelektion sql, int position, TabPane tabpane, Image image){
        this.activeSelections=activeSelections;
        this.sql=sql;
        this.position=position;
        this.tabpane=tabpane;
        this.image=image;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        updateProgress(1,2);
        selectionExecuter(sql, position);
        updateProgress(2,2);
        return null;
    }

    public void createSelectionTab(String titel, ArrayList<String> selektion, DatabaseSelektion sql, int position) {
        if (activeSelections <= MAX_SELECTION_TABS) {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
            tab.setGraphic(iv);
            tab.setOnCloseRequest((Event t) -> {
                TabRessourceCleaner cleaner = new TabRessourceCleaner(tabController.get(this.tabpane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
                Thread th = new Thread(cleaner);
                th.start();
                tabController.remove(this.tabpane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                activeSelections--;
                System.gc();
            });
            tab.setClosable(true);
            tab.setText(titel);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if(position>0){
                tabpane.getTabs().add(position, tab);
            }else if(position==-1){
                tabpane.getTabs().add(tab);
                System.out.println(tabpane);
                System.out.println(tab);
            } 
            });
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/fxml_tab.fxml"));
            Controller_tab tabCont = new Controller_tab();
            tabCont.setTabTitel(tab.getText());
            tabCont.setSelektionAdresses(selektion);
            tabCont.setActiveSelection(sql);
            loader.setController(tabCont);
            try {
                tab.setContent((Node) loader.load());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller_main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            tabController.put(tab, tabCont);
            activeSelections++;
        } else {
            createInformaionMessage("Zu viele Selektionen",
                    "Die maximale Anzahl an gleichzeitigen Selektionen liegt bei " + MAX_SELECTION_TABS + " Stück.\n"
                    + "Um eine neue Selektion auszuführen, schließ bitte eine vorhandene");
        }
    }

    private void selectionExecuter(DatabaseSelektion sql, int position) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        System.out.println("1");
        String query = sql.getSelection_sql();
        System.out.println("2");
        if(query.contains("%bearbeiter")){
            query=query.replace("%bearbeiter", currentUser.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("3");
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList();
        for (DatabaseCustomer db : DatabaseThreadExecuter.executeSelektion(query)) {
            if (db != null) {
                temp.add(db.getAdressnummer());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("4");
        if (temp.size() >= 1) {
            temp.trimToSize();
            System.out.println("5");
            createSelectionTab(sql.getSelection_name()+" - "+temp.size(), temp, sql, position);
            temp.clear();
        } else {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
            MessageHelper.createInformaionMessage("Fehlerhafte Selektion", "Die Selektion enhält keine Einträge, Sie wurde nicht geöffnet");
            });
        }
        System.out.println("6");
        temp.clear();
    }
}
```

And here is how i start it:

```
private void executeSelection(ActionEvent event) {
        DatabaseSelektion sql = selectionStore.get(combo_selections.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
        CreateSelections task = new CreateSelections(activeSelections, sql, -1, tabpane, image);
        openSelectionProgress(task);
        executor.execute(task);
        try {
            task.get();
            if(selectionProgressStage!=null){
                selectionProgressStage.close();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller_main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller_main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Ok now some informations:

In the task im going to send a query to the databaseDatabaseThreadExecuter.executeSelektion(query) after that i iterate over the list which is send back from my server. After that i add i to a new class in which i use it. So my question is now.

if i use task.get() in my executeSelection it works with no problems. It runs until number 4 stops for a while (database query) and then it goes further to 5 and 6.

if i dont use task.get() in my executeSelection method is runs until number 4 and then the execution stops. I dont know why this happens. In the ThreadExecuter class im also waiting for the finnish of my db query. That means, that the result is 100% in memory and ready to use by the CreateSelection task. Can you explain me, why this happens?

What i want to reach is, that it is executet in the background and i dont have to force my ui thread to wait for finnish ... Thats totaly out of sense for me. I start a thread, for the reason, that my main thread dont have to stop but with task.get() i have to wait and block my ui thread.

Comment: I think you are looking for [setOnSucceeded()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) of the Task class.

Comment: But which piece of my code have to be in this method?

Comment: The part which you want to execute after the thread has completed its execution.

Comment: I have not code i want to execute after complete. The thread creates a new tab and adds an arraylist to it. After that the thread has finnished

Comment: What do you want to achieve then? From your last paragraph `i dont have to force my ui thread to wait for finnish`, it sounds to *me* as if you want to execute something when the task ends.

Comment: No its so if i use task.get() it waits until the thread is finnished and this foces my ui to hang. If i dont use task.get() my thread stops at number 3 (see selectionExecuter method in thread). I dont understand why it holds without task.get() but with it runs until end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98686/discussion-between-steinliiippp-and-itachiuchiha).